# Nuget misbehaving with newtonsoft.json package

Tags: c#, json.net, nuget, nuget-package

Why Nuget producing an error when I install a package after `Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.2` is installed. Whenever I try to install another package I get the following error

```
Install-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2' 
from source 'C:\Users\yusuf\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Eman\packages'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package MaterialDesignThemes
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets. 
   InstallPackageCommand
```

Whenever i remove the line with the Newtonsoft.json package defined in `packages.config` the package installs successfully. Is it something wrong with json package itself or is it my package manager that's messed up, anyway can someone show me how i can fix this.

**P.S.** This happens with whichever package i try to install while json package is already installed.

**EDIT** I tried deleting the package line in `packages.config` and also deleting the downloaded package files and reinstalled the package several times, i keep getting the same problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617584/nuget-retrieving-package-metadata

Comment: I tried  that solution several times, didn't work @torsan

Comment: @SF1Dev has a very good answer for this issue, please refer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45225236/5448364

Answer (score 1):

First, downgrade Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.2 to Newtonsoft.Json v6.0.4. Second, install another nuget package.

If the package successfully installs, upgrade Newtonsoft.Json v6.0.4 back to Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.2.