# cannot add controller in .net RestApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to build a read only .net rest api using the following tutorial on Microsoft Docs-(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api)

According to the tutorial when i add a controller the following error popup.[image]

I have tried other solutions on stackoverflow like

- Clearing ComponentModelCache
- Also deleting .vs folder in solution 
  But nothing helped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for \*\*\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103492/an-error-occurred-while-retrieving-package-metadata-for)

Comment: No this does not solve the problem

Comment: As a workaround for now, I suggest u to just copy your already existing "WeatherForecastController" and change the name

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your project to `.NET Framework` instead of `.NET Core` and make sure you are able to create a solution with `.NET Framework`. If the issue still persists please provide some additional log details of VisualStudio when creating with `.NET Core`

Comment: But that is not going to be a solution. If i want the benefits of .net core than this solution will not be valid.

Comment: The link you shared was referring to .NET Framework 4.5 as because of which I asked you to try it out with FW instead of core.

Comment: The same problem is occurring in .net framework as well