# Error While installing the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v.7.0.10

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget

While installing the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (v.7.0.10) using nuget package manager in visual studio, i got an error.
Below is the error i got:
**Error NU5000 An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.1.1.0' from source 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'.**

i don't got any error when installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer(6.0.21) (last version before 7.0);
But i got the error i mentioned above in all versions starting from 7.0.

In my PC there is Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.1.1.0 folder in NuGetFallbackFolder and all packages are available in this folder.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103492/an-error-occurred-while-retrieving-package-metadata-for

Answer (score 0):

Please share the app type on your side.

And you can try to clean the nuget cahce and change the package source in this situation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After that, close VS, remove the .vs folder in the solution folder, and then reopen VS:

[image]

Comment: Did not fix it for me unfortunately. I am using visual studio 2022 v.17.7 and the application I am getting this error is Asp.Net core MVC.

Comment: @almiracan What is the nuget source you are using, is it nuget gallery api? If not, try to use it and check whether the issue exists. :)

Comment: I`m using "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" and the issue exists while using this Nuget Gallery api version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I selected the .net6 version as the target framework.